# Smalltalk wait for a active process

Tags: join, process, wait, smalltalk

I have the following code:

```
newProc := [self doSth] newProcess.
newProc resume.
self doOtherJob.
newProc wait. "<- here is the question"
```

In the last line I would like to wait for the process, till it is ready with the work. Unfortunately there is no method 'wait' in Process. Do I have to write my own wait routine or is there arleady something, that I didn't find yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally by Camillo Bruni:

Semaphores are your friends:

```
semaphore := Semaphore new.

[ ... First Job ...
    semaphore signal. ] fork.

[ ... Second Job ...
    semaphore signal. ] fork.

"consume to signals, aka. pause this thread until both jobs have finished"
semaphore wait; wait.
```

In your case you have to do:

```
semaphore := Semaphore new.
newProc := [
    self doSth.
    semaphore signal ] newProcess.
newProc resume.
self doOtherJob.
semaphore wait.
```

Comment: Maybe use a semaphore with timeout to ensure that the semaphore will be signaled eventually.

Comment: How can I get this functionality without blocking the main thread responsible for the user interface?

Comment: @AMomchilov you just wrap everything in a block and send it `fork`. The the semaphore wait will happen in the process, and not in your main UI process

Comment: Hah yes I figured that out! :) I wasn't thinking straight lol